# Is this a real question?

Tags: discussion

This question was recently flagged as "Not a real question".

I'd like a bit of feedback before we move forward on it.

[Salty flavor in beer?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/salty-flavor-in-beer)

Thanks

Comment: Whoops, I didn't see this before I dealt with the flag...   sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a real question. But I'm biased.

I suppose with the guidelines this is not relevant to homebrewing, but it's definitely a real question.. something for a science site, perhaps. I don't think his flag is appropriate, however. "Not a valid question for the site" might be better.

Comment: I think it could probably be rephrased to better reflect brewing/flavor concerns  (i.e. remove the multiple choice part and turn those sentences into questions (in the english sense, not the SE sense))

Comment: Most likely. I was but a wee lad then.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize that it was asked in January 2010.    I'm definitely fine with leaving it after that amount of time.